# Transform time-dependent data

Tags: regression

I have pollution data (quantitative) plotted against time (categorical), the hours of the day. Via ANOVA testing I've found significance at many of the hours, however, the relationship is definitely not linear. For example, it tends to rise in the morning, lower in the afternoon, and rise again in the evening, as you can see in the picture:

[image: pollution data]

How can I transform this data set in order to build a linear model (in R) ?

I've chopped the data up into 6 groups of 4 hours to find average means of each group, but I'd like to be able to say, with a level of significance, that time X is the most polluted, or least polluted. How can I use R to make such a statement?

I've plotted the residuals of the model below -- since it's not normally distributed -- there is something that the linear model is not capturing.

[image: pollution resid]

I've put my data in a time series object - but I don't know what it means:

```
myts = ts(df$value, start=c(0), end=c(24), frequency=24)
plot(stl(log(myts), s.window="periodic"))
```

[image: time series]

I now have a model, but not a very good one. It has an adjusted r-squared of .18.

```
plot(value~(hour), data=df, ylim=c(0, 300))
my.lm = lm(value ~ 
                       sin(100*hour) + 
                       sin(50*hour) +  
                       cos(100*hour) + 
                       cos(50*hour) + 
                       day + 
                       month,
             data=df)
lines(predict(my.lm), col=3, lwd=10)
```

Any thoughts on what I could do better?

[image: graph]
[image: summary]

Comment: As 24:00 = 00:00 you should be thinking about a model periodic in time of day. Using sines and cosines as predictors would be a linear model. If your original data are recorded more finely than hour of day, use the precise times. Blocking into hour groups would just degrade your data, as to a good first approximation pollution will vary continuously with time of day. If you have reason to suppose that emissions from some source start and/or stop abruptly, that might need to be built in. Analysis of variance treating hours as categorical predictors is a poor model here and quite unphysical.

Comment: Questions here should be statistical and not focused on specific syntax for specific software.

Comment: +1 to [@NickCox's comment](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/124816/transform-time-dependent-data#comment237887_124816). An alternative would be periodic splines, e.g., B-splines. I personally don't like how sines and cosines fit *global* effects.

Comment: Here, as so often, there is a mismatch between your graphics and your analysis. Box plots show medians; ANOVA uses means. It's entirely likely that they tell consistent stories here, but watch out. More importantly, it is far from obvious that means are the best summaries here or that data should be analysed as they come rather than by using a transformed scale or a non-identity link function.

Comment: To my eye some values of your variable appear negative: is that right?

Comment: @NickCox no, there shouldn't be any values below 0. its possible that there are a few in there that are -1, but that just means that the system recorded an incorrect value

Comment: @NickCox I've read up a bit on b-slines and sin/cos transformations, though I think that's still a bit beyond my pay grade. any ideas on where to get a good start?

Comment: That's B-splines, on which @Stephan Kolassa may have some suggestions. Make sure you implement a periodic flavour, or in such a way that the fit is periodic in practice. On sines and cosines, www.stata-journal.com/sjpdf.html?articlenum=st0116 may help. The equivalent R code shouldn't be difficult (but is off-topic here).

Comment: To repeat, ANOVA as you have applied it makes very little sense here as it is not focused on capturing the obvious and natural periodic structure in the data. (I'd reject any paper based on such analysis as fatally flawed.) Impossible negative values should be recoded to missings. I'd recommend a generalized linear model with some skewed probability distribution family and log link and periodic predictors.

Comment: @NickCox makes some *extremely* good points. On (B-)splines, I found Frank Harrell's [*Regression Modeling Strategies*](http://www.amazon.com/Regression-Modeling-Strategies-Applications-Statistics/dp/0387952322) very helpful as an introduction. I don't have it here, but I seem to remember him discussing B-splines in particular, though not explicitly a periodic version (which you, as @NickCox notes, would need here), but this extension is completely straightforward. In R, look at `bs()` in the `splines` package.